# Migration not inserting data to table?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, migration, database-migration

The below migration is running successfully with no errors but it's not inserting any data do table. Why it can be? can some one tell me what is wrong here?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddValuesTOBusiness extends Migration
{
   
    public function up()
    {
       //  Schema::table('business', function (Blueprint $table) {
            DB::table('business')->insertOrIgnore([[
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'fg',
                'description' => 'best IT & software solutions',
                'clientAddress' => 'fdgd 682028',
                'status' => 'active',
                'email' => 'fg@y.com',
                'phone' => 3455645656,
                'appInfo' => 'learningApp',
                'defaultClient' => true,
                'eustardApp' => true,
                'sellerCategory' => 'internal',
                'created_at' => now()]
            ]);
       // }
    }

    public function down()
    {
      // Schema::table('business', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::table('business')->truncate();
      //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting any error because you are using "insertOrIgnore", this method does not throw any error but simply ignores and moves forward.
Your error is probably some data validation, for example, the id that should be set automatically by the database.

Try using the "insert" method instead and you'll probably get the error you are looking for